How can I use a browser extension's API within a standard website?
I'm curious about the feasibility of using the browser extension's API directly from a standard website. Specifically, I want to understand if there's a way to interact with the browser API from my web page's JavaScript while complying with all security measures. I have some background in developing extensions, so I'm familiar with content scripts, background scripts, and message passing. Still, I'm unsure if it's possible and how to apply these concepts in this context. It should be impossible, but asking is better than giving up.
Here are some aspects I'm curious about:

Is it possible for a web page to call a browser API?
Ensure that such interaction complies with browser security policies and respects user privacy. In extensions, this is the role of the manifest.json. Is there any other similar tool for websites?

From my understanding, content scripts might play a role, but I am unclear on how to set this up securely. Can anyone provide insights, examples or prototypes? I'm super curious about them.
To be clear, I'm currently developing an extension, not a website, but I want to explore, go crazy, and see all the possibilities and constraints. Any pointers to relevant, meaningful documentation or information would be greatly appreciated! They should be related to websites, not extensions.

You cannot use a browser extension API in a regular webpage. Other browser APIs? Yes.

I think you should try it yourself before asking.

"Ensure that such interaction complies with browser security policies and respects user privacy." - not sure what you're thinking of there. Either the website can access the API, or it can't?

@evolutionxbox yeah that's the feeling i'm getting until now.

@NorioYamamoto that's true, but previous comment suggests it should not be possible.
Trying it should be equialent to a security research project about finding bug on specific browsers exploitable from a visited site. if so, i belive It's a bit too much for me.

@Bergi, this point should be far more understandable to anyone who wrote an extension. Indeed, the complete point provides an example.
In the manifest.json, the developer declares which browser API the extension will/can use. This information empowers the user to make an informed decision about installing and using the extension.
If a visited site could pass something similar to gain access to some browser API upon the user's consent, then "the game is on", and it becomes possible to use browser API from a site.

I would hope browser extensions and web page JS run in different contexts. Why not make a POC?

@Hodor If a website can access it, it's by definition no longer a browser API but a web API. Notice there are already a lot of web APIs that require explicit opt-in by the user before the website can call the API, like access to geolocation, media (microphone/camera) and clipboard. There are no "manifests" though, it uses the Permissions API.


Is it possible for a web page to call a browser API?

No. By definition, that would make it a Web API.

Ensure that such interaction complies with browser security policies and respects user privacy. In extensions, this is the role of the manifest.json. Is there any other similar tool for websites?

Yes, some Web API require explicit opt-in by the user to grant access to sensitive data. This is not done via a declarative manifest though, rather through the Permissions API. Some older methods also simply prompt the user upon first use of the API, then remember their decision, and return a rejected promise if access is not granted.
